# Can't get simple tensorflow logistic regression program to work with sigmoid activation function.

Tags: python, tensorflow, logistic-regression

I've got a very simple logistic regression tensorflow program that looks like this:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import model_selection
import sys

gender_df = pd.read_csv('data/binary_data.csv')

# Shuffle our data
gender_df = gender_df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

print (gender_df.columns)

train_x,test_x, train_y, test_y = model_selection.train_test_split(gender_df['HEIGHT'],gender_df['GENDER'],test_size = 0.3)

tmp = np.asarray(train_x)
tmp.resize([train_x.shape[0],1])
train_x = tmp

tmp = np.asarray(train_y)
tmp = np.resize(tmp,[train_y.shape[0],2])
train_y = tmp

tmp = np.asarray(test_x)
tmp.resize([test_x.shape[0],1])
test_x = tmp

tmp = np.asarray(test_y)
tmp = np.resize(tmp,[test_y.shape[0],2])
test_y = tmp

n_samples = train_x.shape[0]

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,2])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,2]),dtype = tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]),dtype = tf.float32)

a = tf.nn.sigmoid((W * x) + b)

learning_rate = 0.001

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-(y*tf.log(a) + (1 - y) * tf.log(1-a)))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for epoch in range(1000):
        _,l = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy], feed_dict = {x: train_x, y:train_y})
        if epoch % 50 == 0:
            print ('loss = %f' %(l))

    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(a,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct,'float'))
    print ('Accuracy: ', accuracy.eval({x: test_x, y:test_y}))
```

It's a fairly simple binary classification logistic regression program that takes 100 lines of sample data that have two columns, Gender has a value either of 0 (female) or 1 (male). 
Height is in centimeters.

I'm trying to do a prediction of gender based on height but the loss value doesn't seem to converge to a minimum, additionally, the cost values and the accuracy vary wildly from one run to the next, even though the data being looked at is the same data.

I can have a run where the accuracy is 0.8 and the next run the accuracy
is 0.2

Also, i noticed for some reason that the first loss value is always:
loss = 0.693147
But, for example the rest of loss calculations can look like this:
loss = 1.397364

loss = 1.397516

loss = 1.397514

loss = 1.397515

loss = 1.397514
...

I'm rather confused about what's happening.
Am I using the right sigmoid function?  From my understanding, I
only  need to use softmax when I have a logistic regression problem with multiple classes and for a simple binary classification, I can use tf.sigmoid().  Also, do I need to add in the 'b' parameter to the sigmoid function? Should I set it to random values rather than zeros?

Also, can someone suggest a simple binary classification problem example using logistic regression and tensorflow that *doesn't* use the mnist or iris databases?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Both your x and y should be of shape [None, 1] and your W simply [1, 1]. Both your input and your output are mono-dimensional.

You could even drop the matrix notation and use simply vectors in this example.

Comment: Thanks.  I dropped the matrix notation and it seemed to make things better, however, I'm now running into a problem when attempting to print out the accuracy.

Comment: Gah.  Forgot to finish.  The error I get is InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected dimension in the range [-1, 1), but got 1
 This occurs in the line where I run accuracy.eval to print out the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

This is again from the perspective of another TensorFlow straggler but I managed to execute this. I couldn't proffer a decent explanation though.

Code is now using a 'one hot' representation and accuracy is 0.84. I just used another dataset but I don't know how many features are optimal. I believe it should work with the original dataset too but I had already switched the datasets when it worked. *Features are numerical.*

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn import preprocessing


data = pd.read_csv('D:/Development_Avector/PycharmProjects/TensorFlow/anes_dataset.csv')
training_features = ['TVnews', 'PID', 'age', 'educ', 'income']
target = 'vote'

print (data.columns)

X = data.loc[:, ['TVnews', 'PID', 'age', 'educ', 'income']]
# y is our labels
y = data.loc[:, ['vote']]

oneHot = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
oneHot.fit(X)
X = oneHot.transform(X).toarray()
oneHot.fit(y)
y = oneHot.transform(y).toarray()
train_x,test_x, train_y, test_y = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1, random_state=0)


n_samples = train_x.shape[0]
print ("There are " + str( n_samples) + " samples")
print ("Shape of train_x is " + str(train_x.shape))
print ("Shape of train_y is " + str(train_y.shape))
print (train_y)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,train_x.shape[1]])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,2])
print ("Shape of y is " + str(y.shape))


W = tf.Variable(np.zeros((train_x.shape[1], 2)),tf.float32,name="W")
b = tf.Variable(0.,dtype = tf.float32)


predicted_y1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,tf.cast(W,tf.float32) ), b)
print (predicted_y1.shape)
predicted_y = tf.nn.softmax(predicted_y1)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = predicted_y, labels = y))


optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0003).minimize(cross_entropy)

s = tf.InteractiveSession()
s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(40000):
    _, loss_i = s.run([optimizer,cross_entropy], {x: train_x, y: train_y})
    print("loss at iter %i:%.4f" % (i, loss_i))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(predicted_y,1), tf.argmax(y,1)), "float"))
accuracy_value = s.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x:test_x, y:test_y})
print (accuracy_value)


loss at iter 0:0.6931
loss at iter 1:0.6929
loss at iter 2:0.6927
loss at iter 3:0.6924
-------------------
loss at iter 39997:0.3599
loss at iter 39998:0.3599
loss at iter 39999:0.3599
0.84210527
```